# How to check current status of API process

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, api, async-await

I have a web api which has responsibility to write something on a files by taking data from somewhere on conditions and than return the file names. What i need is to check the status of this task.
It can happen that api will start write after 2 mins so that the status of this api should be not started till that time. How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Start from here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When you write "I need to check the status" I think you mean "I have a separate program which must retrieve the status from the API process." Is that right? If so, what is the nature of the program?

Comment: A separate program or same program, this program will be async